# Nested new commands yields undefined control sequence

Tags: math-mode, macros, pdftex, amsmath

I defined new commands in a Latex document. Even though the pdf render is correct, compiler raises "undefined control sequence" error. Could you help me identifying the problem?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\textKeyCommitGeneral}{ O{x} O{p} }{c^{#1}_{#2}} % Key commit representation general
\NewDocumentCommand{\expKeyCommitGeneral}{ O{x} O{p} }{$c^{#1}_{#2}$\xspace} % Key commit representation general

\NewDocumentCommand{\textCoSCKGeneral}{ O{x} O{p} }{K(\textKeyCommitGeneral[#1][#2])} % DCoS-C Analysis K general
\NewDocumentCommand{\expCoSCKGeneral}{ O{x} O{p} }{$\textCoSCKGeneral[#1][#2]$\xspace} % DCoS-C Analysis K general

\begin{document}


\expCoSCKGeneral

\end{document}
```

Comment: You've used `\xspace` but not loaded the relevant package - was that deliberate?

Comment: Thank you @JosephWright, the snippet is the trimmed version of a big document. I was unaware of the fact that I did not load `\xspace`. It solved the problem :sweating_face:.

Comment: Don’t use `xspace` in general.

Comment: @Gaussler Is there any other way to insert a space after a new command?

Comment: Yes. Use `\command{} `, `\command\ `, or `{\command}`. These are the methods that were meant to be used since the creation of TeX. I prefer the first two. On the contrary, `\xspace` is error-prone. The problem is that TeX cannot distinguish `\command<non-space token>` from `\command<spaces><non-space token>`. What `\xspace` does is go to the next non-space token character, and based on that, it tries to guess whether or not you want a space. This sometimes yields unintended results. The package `xspace` was originally written by @DavidCarlisle who never uses it and explicitly discourages it.

Comment: Thank you @Gaussler for the detailed explanation. I will adapt that practice.

Comment: I'd define `\newcommand\foo[1]{#1}` (foo being an acronym for first of one) and do `\foo{\command}`. After tokenizing a control-word-token like `\command` TeX's reading apparatus is in state S (skipping blanks). After tokenizing an explicit character-token like  `}` TeX's reading apparatus is in state M (middle of line)., thus after `}` a subsequent space is not skipped/discarded but tokenized as explicit space token probably yielding horizontal glue in horizontal mode/restricted horizontal mode.